# Why does the floordiv (//) opertor with python decimals round toward 0 instead of negative infinity?

Tags: python, language-lawyer

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal(-7) // 4
Decimal('-1') # Result rounded towards 0.
>>> -7 // 4
-2  # Result rounded towards negative infinity.
```

Why does the floordiv operator with a python decimal round towards 0 instead of towards negative infinity, as the floordiv operator does with all other types?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) says that it does, at the part after "There are some small differences between arithmetic on Decimal objects and arithmetic on integers and floats." but it doesn't say *why*.

Comment: I don't know what the motivation of the authors of the `decimal` module was, but perhaps it is preserving [associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property): `(-7) // 4` => `-2` and `-(7 // 4)` => `-1`, while `decimal.Decimal(-7) // 4` => `Decimal('-1')` and `-(decimal.Decimal(7) // 4)` => `Decimal('-1')`

Comment: Yes I saw the documentation mentions that, but was curious why this decision was made.

Comment: The `decimal` module fully implements the IBM [Decimal Arithmetic Specification](https://speleotrove.com/decimal/daops.html#refdivint) which specifies it that way.  Ask IBM :^)

Comment: An expression of a high-level motivation can be found in [the implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/_pydecimal.py): "The purpose of this module is to support arithmetic using familiar "schoolhouse" rules and to avoid some of the tricky representation issues associated with binary floating point."
Perhaps in their opinion that includes associativity as mentioned above.

Btw there are alternative [rounding modes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#rounding-modes) that might deliver the behavior you expected.

Comment: @RobertHaas Your examples have nothing to do with associativity. It seems you misunderstood what that is.

Comment: @KellyBundy what I wanted to express is that the order of operations changes the result in case of integers, but does not in case of Decimals. In doing that, I considered 1) the unary operation `-` and 2) the binary operation `//` as the two operations whose order can be swapped to see if the result changes. In that sense the decimals implementation behaves associative. Now, I'm not sure if there's a standard definition of associativity that limits it strictly to binary operations. If so, then I was wrong to use that word for it, and you are right.

But perhaps you meant another issue?

Comment: @RobertHaas That's what I meant, yes. And yes, there is a standard definition of associativity that limits it strictly to binary operations. You linked to it :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy Do you know if there's a name for what I described in my example? It seems like a straightforward generalization of associativity, especially when looking at the functional definition `f(f(x, y), z) = f(x, f(y, z))` on Wikipedia, where you can easily change the number of functions and arguments. Thanks for making me aware of this point, I didn't know the term is reserved for the case of a single binary operator.

Comment: @RobertHaas No, I don't know a term for what you described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [BPO-12005](https://bugs.python.org/issue12005) (formatting mine):

> The specification on which the `decimal` module is based requires that there be a 'remainder' operation with the semantics of `Decimal`'s `%` operation (i.e., the result of `x % y` has the sign of `x`). However, the specification doesn't say anything about how the prescribed operations should map to language constructs.
>
> So the choice was between (1) leaving `%` for `Decimal` objects unimplemented, and providing a separate 'remainder' method, or (2) mapping `%` to `Decimal`'s remainder operation, and accepting the slight mismatch between the `%` semantics for `float` and `Decimal`.
>
> Perhaps the wrong choice was made. But it's there now, and to me it's not so obviously wrong that it's worth the upheaval of deprecating `%` for `Decimal` objects.
>
> — [Mark Dickinson](https://github.com/mdickinson) (May 5, 2011)

The post above is about `%`, but this also applies to `//`.